# Cannot find text with Autohotkey

Tags: testing, autohotkey

I am trying to use AutoHotKey to do some basic UI testing of an application. I want to test an "Add" button that adds a user. I am trying to validate the addition test by checking if the user's name is added to the relevant column. However, I am not able to check at all if the user's name is in the column because none of the window's controls are being recognized for me to use WinGetText. Just using WinGetText for the parent window itself doesnt work. 
Any suggestions on what to do / how i can change my validation process? 
Thanks :)

Comment: What do you see when you use AutoHotKey Window Spy?

Comment: i see all the details of the parent window and nothing else. when i use the details of the parent window for wingettext, i dont get any text.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? I think that you miss the A at the end of the command like this: WinGetText, text, A  ; The active window will be used.

Comment: Also, what kind of application is it? Windows Native / Java / Something else? If, for example, it's a Java app it might be difficult to get the text using ahk.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going through Citrix? If so, windows Spy won't be able to see past the parent citrix window (by design).

The way i deal with your situation is IF the control has the ability to select text, I copy that to the clipboard then check the clipboard value against my variable...